# Getting DNS for Load Balancer in GCP

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

In Google Kubernetes Engine, I created a Load Balancer (External IP Address). I can access it using the IP address. However, I want to get a domain name. ( I am not asking about buying my own domain and adding DNS records ). I am not able to find how to get the url.

For eg. in Azure, in Azure Kubernetes Service, I created a Load Balancer and added a label. So, I can get a url like http://<dns_label_which_i_gave>.<region_name>.cloudapp.azure.com. So, for trial purpose, I don't have to pay for a domain and I can get an easy to read domain name.

How to get the same in GCP Load Balancer?

Comment: You can add a service label to the load-balance front-end and it will provide a DNS https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/dns-names

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With Google Cloud you can't do this. The Load balancer expose an IP and you have to create a A record in your registrar to make the link.